# Anylogic: Pie Chart dataset

Tags: charts, dataset, anylogic

I am doing a simulation and I need to create a **pie chart** with three datasets. Simple. But Anylogic keeps giving me an error.

Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataSet to double.

How do I say, put this **dataset into the value**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pie chart in AnyLogic requires double values to be used, and that's it... if you want to use datasets you need to create your own piechart

But now let's imagine you have a dataset with some values, and you want to add all the values to the piechart, you can do the following:

```
ArrayList <DataItem> dataItems=new ArrayList();
chart.removeAll();
for(int i=0;i<dataset.size();i++){
    dataItems.add(new DataItem());
    dataItems.get(i).setValue(dataset.getY(i));
    chart.addDataItem(dataItems.get(i));
}
```

Which will generate a chart (piechart) that will contain the values of your dataset in it.
Your piechart has to start empty

Comment: Thank you. So...I don't necessarily need to use datasets, it can be just variables if that would work as well...I have just few variables with number of people and they all are members of different group so I wanted to create a pie chart to see the percentage among these groups..